# Why does an explicit "extern" not allocate storage for an object?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, declaration, definition, extern

I've been diving deeper into the C standard, and I'm confused about the way it talks about linkage and tentative definitions.

First, in [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) part of the standard it is stated that

> extern (keyword) means static duration and external linkage (unless already declared internal)

> static storage duration. The storage duration is the entire execution of the program, and the value
> stored in the object is initialized only once, prior to main function. All objects declared static and
> all objects with either internal or external linkage that aren't declared _Thread_local (since C11)
> have this storage duration.

> external linkage. The identifier can be referred to from any other translation units in the entire
> program. All non-static functions, all extern variables (unless earlier declared static), and all file-
> scope non-static variables have this linkage.

so far we have that variables declared in file scope have static storage duration and external linkage by default. Also, objects with static storage duration are initialized to zero, before the program starts.

But, after reading [this part](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern) (tentative definitions) and [this part](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations#Definitions) (declarations) I can't find where it says that objects with an explicit "extern" keyword are not allocated storage.

Please be careful about the difference between the "extern" keyword itself and the term "external declarations".

"External declarations" are defined as

> At the top level of a translation unit (that is, a source file with all the #includes after the preprocessor), every C program is a sequence of declarations, which declare functions and objects with external linkage. These declarations are known as external declarations because they appear outside of any function.

regardless of the presence or absence of an explicit "extern" keyword.

I suppose that my concrete question is where in the standard does it say that file scope objects, that have an implicit external linkage by default, are not allocated storage if they are declared with an explicit "extern".

I know this is the case because if one declares the same identifier in multiple translation units all but one must have "extern" so as not to get a redefinition error.

Comment: I do not think there is an explicit place that says a declaration for an identifier for an object with `extern` and without an initializer is not a definition or does not reserve space. Rather, the standard has a section that specifies declarations and has various places that say certain declarations are definitions (such as if they have an initializer) and leaves declarations-that-are-not-definitions characterized by the absence of them being specified to be definitions.

Answer (score 3):

First, while cppreference.com has useful information it is not the C standard.  The C11 standard can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

This comes down to the difference between a *declaration* and a *definition*.

For an object, a **declaration** basically states that an object with a given type exists *somewhere*, while a **definition** is what actually allocates space for the object.

These terms are specified in sectin 6.7p5 of the C standard:

> A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of
> identifiers.  A *definition* of an identifier is a declaration for
> that identifier that:
>
> - for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
> - for a function, includes the function body;
> - for an enumeration constant, is the (only) declaration of the identifier;
> - for a typedef name, is the first (or only) declaration of the identifier.

By applying the `extern` keyword, if there is no initializer then this constitutes a *declaration*, and a declaration does not allocate storage for an object.  Section 6.9.2p1-2 spells this out:

> *1* If  the  declaration  of  an  identifier  for  an  object  has  file  scope  and  an  initializer,  the declaration is an external
> definition for the identifier.
>
> *2* A declaration  of  an  identifier  for  an  object  that  has  file
> scope  without  an  initializer, and without a storage-class specifier
> or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a tentative
> definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
> definitions for an identifier, and  the  translation  unit  contains
> no  external  definition  for  that  identifier, then the  behavior
> is  exactly  as  if  the  translation  unit  contains  a  file  scope
> declaration  of  that identifier, with the composite type as of the
> end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

A declaration with `extern` and no initializer does not fit the above definition of a *tentative definition* or an *external definition*.

Section 6.9.2p4 gives examples of declarations and definitions:

> ```
> int i1 = 1;         //definition, external linkage
> static int i2 = 2;  //definition, internal linkage
> extern int i3 = 3;  //definition, external linkage
> int i4;             //tentative definition, external linkage
> static int i5;      //tentative definition, internal linkage
>
> int i1;             //valid tentative definition, refers to previous
> int i2;             //6.2.2 renders undefined, linkage disagreement
> int i3;             //valid tentative definition, refers to previous
> int i4;             //valid tentative definition, refers to previous
> int i5;             //6.2.2 renders undefined, linkage disagreement
>
> extern int i1;      //refers to previous, whose linkage is external
> extern int i2;      //refers to previous, whose linkage is internal
> extern int i3;      //refers to previous, whose linkage is external
> extern int i4;      //refers to previous, whose linkage is external
> extern int i5;      //refers to previous, whose linkage is internal
> ```

Comment: And it is clearly seen in this example: https://godbolt.org/z/sKsTEz4r1 (UV for good explanation)

Answer (score 1):

In the C Standard (6.9.2 External object definitions ) there is written that

> 1 If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and
> **an initializer**, the declaration is an external definition for the
> identifier.

So if you will write at file scope

```
extern int x = 1;
```

then this declaration with the storage-class specifier `extern` will be at the same time a definition of the object `x`.

Otherwise if an object is declared at file scope without an initializer but with the storage-class specifier `extern` then the compiler assumes that the object is defined in some other translation unit or in the same translation unit but somewhere else.

For example (here is declared a variable at file scope with internal linkage)

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int x = 10;

extern int x;

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If an object is declared at file scope without the storage-class specifier `extern` then the compiler generates a tentative definition.